# Need to show updated data only after all tables has updated

Tags: sql-server

I have three tables Table1, Table2, Table3. Every day data will update in these tables. Table1 takes 30min to update completely, Table2 takes 45min and Table3 takes 1hr. I have to show updated data to user only after all tables update process completed.

What would be the possible way to achieve this?

Comment: I assume the tables are updated only via the long-running batch processes. Do you want users to see the original (stale) data during the update?

Comment: You could log *somewhere*, in your ETL process, the steps in a table. Then you can simple query the table to ensure that a completion log for Table1, Table2, and Table3 exist.

Comment: Assuming your daily process is the only thing that writes to these tables, you could load the data into separate tables, and switch them in all at once when all tables are updated. See [this](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/t-sql-tuesday-schema-switch-a-roo) & [this](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/04/t-sql-queries/schema-switch-a-roo-part-2); you could also use synonyms or views you change after ETL. (Also see Kendra Little's ideas around [using proper partition switching](https://www.littlekendra.com/2017/01/19/why-you-should-switch-in-staging-tables-instead-of-renaming/).)

Answer (score 0):

Your most likely approach here is to use triggers on the tables to create logs.  But there are some warnings that go along with that.

Firstly triggers are like a hidden functionality, there get commonly overlooked and in the future it's likely that someone will be scratching their head wondering where the log data came from.  They aren't bad practice, but thats human nature.

Secondly triggers add overhead to the process.  every insert/update/delete on the initial tables will trigger an event to write to the logs, and those writes do take resources.

Thirdly depending on how you decide to build your logs there will be the overhead to compare the "inserted" and "deleted" tables behind each initial write.

Things to consider are: Do you want to keep the whole previous record and whole new record? Do you want to only store changes?  How much space is this log going to take in the db?  Do you want these triggers to only be active during the process or 24/7?

Triggers can cause issues but are likely to be the best option provided you are careful.